# How to Create Edge with Create vertex in OrientDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I am trying to create an vertex in Purchases class along with its link to Users class vertex. Following example may help you to understand what I am trying to achieve.

```
Create Edge PurchasedCarts
    FROM
    (CREATE VERTEX Purchases SET guid = "44b4dab7-744a-4f13-ae55-3a563e327de9", accountId = '240059', amount = 44, orderNumber = "1496890", totalItems = 2)
    TO
    (Select @rid from Users)
```

Above command producing this error

```
Error parsing query:
Create Edge PurchasedCarts         FROM         (CREATE VERTEX Purchases SET guid = "44b4dab7-744a-4f13-ae55-3a563e327de9", accountId = '240059', amount = 44, orderNumber = "1496890", totalItems = 2)         TO         (Select @rid from Users)
     ^
Encountered " &lt;CREATE&gt; "Create "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    &lt;SELECT&gt; ...
    &lt;TRAVERSE&gt; ...
    &lt;MATCH&gt; ...
    &lt;INSERT&gt; ...
    &lt;RETURN&gt; ...
    &lt;PROFILE&gt; ...
    &lt;FIND&gt; ...
    &lt;REBUILD&gt; ...
    &lt;OPTIMIZE&gt; ...
    &lt;GRANT&gt; ...
    &lt;REVOKE&gt; ...
    &lt;BEGIN&gt; ...
    &lt;COMMIT&gt; ...
    &lt;ROLLBACK&gt; ...
    &lt;IF&gt; ...
    &lt;SLEEP&gt; ...
    &lt;CONSOLE&gt; ...

    DB name="*****"
```

Please help me with that or if you can suggest some other better technique I will be very thankful.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You could use [batch](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html)

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE VERTEX` statement doesn't support that, but you can use the `INSERT INTO` in addition with `UNSAFE` keyword:

```
insert into PurchasedCarts set out=(insert into Purchases SET guid = "44b4dab7-744a-4f13-ae55-3a563e327de9", accountId = '240059', amount = 44, orderNumber = "1496890", totalItems = 2), in=(select from Users) unsafe
```

---

PS

about the destination SELECT use `select from Users`  instead of `select @rid from Users`

Comment: What is the benefit of avoiding @rid ?